# How to avoid table or other hack to align text with tabs in HTML 5?

Tags: html, css

Any way to align text like we do with tabs without table or hacks?

For example this:

```
Name: John
Lastname: Doe
```

output like this:

[image: output]

Comment: you want pure css and html solution, right?

Comment: Check the use of flexbox

Comment: Yes, something more modern that float hack or spaces or html tables

Comment: please check the answer i provided and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `css grid` to achieve this.

```css
.main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
    grid-column-gap : 15px;
    grid-row-gap: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div> Name:  </div>
  <div> John </div>
  <div> Last Name: </div>
  <div> Doe </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please let me know if this solves your problem or i will provide other solution.

Comment: is it possible to set a padding of the grid "cell"?

Comment: may i know for what you need padding?

Comment: just founded I guess :-)  grid-row-gap: 10px; grid-column-gap: 30px;

Comment: @al404IT you can use `grid-column-gap` and `grid-row-gap` to the `.main` with value in `px`

Comment: Exactly @al404IT

Answer (score -1):

```css
div.text {
width:100px;
float:left;
}
You can set width for div
```

```html
<div class="text">Name :</div> John
<br>
<div class="text">Lastname :</div> Deo
```